# How to make specific physics animation

Tags: graphics, manipulate, probability-or-statistics, animation, physics

I'm thinking about adding some animations in Mathematica to my last Physics assignment and I don't quite know where to start.

Id like to make somthing like this image:

[image]

which I made using PowerPoint and IguanaTeX, and I'd like to control the number of blue dots using Manipulate[]. I mean, I have an expression which gives me the number of blue dots that should appear in any of the two levels, so I'd like to make something using Manipulate in order to be able to see how the number of blue dots in each level changes as I change the parameters of my expression.

I have the background image (I can erase the blue dots in the one I am showing you) but I don't know how to control the blue dots.

Could you give me some hints? Thank you for your help!

Comment: It is always better for future users and those who wish to help answer to post code with your question. It is also better practice to wait a bit before accepting an answer so that others may submit their attempts at answers. Welcome to Mathematica.SE!

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll try next time! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
prolog = Graphics[{Join[{Black, Arrow[{{-1, 0}, {-1, 5}}], Orange, 
 Line[{{{0, 2}, {10, 2}}, {{0, 0}, {10, 0}}}], Green}, 
Table[Arrow[{{i, 3}, {i, 5}}], {i, 7, 9}]]}];
dots[n_Integer] :=
Graphics[{Blue, Table[Disk[{4 + i, 2}, 0.1], {i, n}]}];
Manipulate[Show[{prolog, dots[n]}], {n, 1, 5, 1}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!! It helped me a lot. I modified it to make some adjustments on the lower level and added some text. Thank you a lot!!!